# How can you distinguish between SMS and MMS if the message is short and contains no media?

Tags: sms, mms

I sent a short message to someone, and I thought I was sending an SMS, but when I asked them if they have read my SMS, they corrected me, and said "yes, I read your MMS". How did they know it's an MMS? What's the difference in this case? I know MMS allows for longer text, and images/videos, but my message was short and contained no media, so how did they know it was MMS and not SMS? What gave it away?

Note that the CRS was enabled. Is this what gave it away?

We both use Samsung phones, although mine is newer.

Comment: SMS are directly sent to the target device. For MMS the target device only gets a data SMS containing the information that there is an MMS available. The device then can connect to the MMS server using data connection and download the MMS. If I remember correctly this should more or less the way it works.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, because when I receive a long message, which means an MMS, I just get the message itself, not a message telling me where to download it.

Comment: The is done automatically by your phone. As I said the first SMS containing the MMS notification is a data SMS, such SMS are never displayed to the user.

Comment: See also the technical description how an MMS is received: 2nd paragraph of the "Technical description": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service#Technical_description The "SMS control message" is the data SMS I was talking about.

Comment: Then again, the question is, how did she know it's MMS if the data SMS is not displayed to the user, but the user directly sees the message?

Comment: That your SMS app does not display the message type does not mean it is not shown by other SMS apps.

Comment: Yeah, that could be. 
Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the apps, some messaging apps have a feature to display whether a message is an SMS, MMS, or RCS; whether it's on a different menu or directly beside the message. RCS feature is unrelated to knowing the message type.

**Google Messages**

1. Long tap the message
2. Select the **overflow menu** (3 vertical dots) on the top-right
3. Tap **View details**
4. **Message Details** will show the type: SMS, MMS, RCS

**Samsung Messages**

1. Long tap the message
2. Select **View details**
3. **Message details** will show the type: Text message (SMS), Multimedia message (MMS)

**Truecaller**

1. Long tap the message
2. Tap **More** on the bottom-right
3. Tap **Message details**
4. The type will be shown under the text: SMS, MMS

---

Also, *RCS messages may be shown as MMS instead on another messaging app.*

| Google Messages (sent with RCS) | Samsung Messages (RCS disabled) | Truecaller (no RCS support) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |